# How to make a Search with VBA through all folders and change the links in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vba

I stuck with one problem. I have my outlook and I have some folders there with messages. I need to go through all these folders and then replace the links in those messages. Is it possible to do?

I used Kutools for detached my attachments and right now I need to change the path of those links.

I found good links:

1. It's probably how we need to check emails:
   https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/5287-outlook-find-and-replace-subject.html
2. It's probably how we can go through all files:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346183/excel-vba-looping-through-all-subfolders-in-outlook-email-to-find-an-email-with

My code didn't work, maybe someone has a solution for it or a link where I can read about it.

My code:

```
Sub GetEmail()

Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Mfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Myitems As Outlook.Items
Dim myitem As Object
Dim Found As Boolean


Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim UserFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
Set Namespace = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set Myitems = myInbox.Items

On Error Resume Next
For Each Folder In Namespace.Folders
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.Folders
        For Each UserFolder In SubFolder.Folders
            For Each myitem In Myitems
                If myitem.Class = olMail Then
                    If InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "sketch") > 0 Then
                    Debug.Print "Found"
                    Found = True
                    'Debug.Print Folder.Name, "|", SubFolder.Name, "|", UserFolder.Name
                    End If
                End If
            Next myitem
        Next UserFolder
    Next SubFolder
Next Folder
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser. We're not a "please write me a script" kind of service. If you provide the script you already made that doesn't work, we can see why its not working and help you from there.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I added it.

Comment: A better Stack Overflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60370414/looping-through-outlook-mail-items. The bare bones here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2273050/1571407.  For the second part of the question this demonstrates how to get to the links  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250586/excel-vba-loop-through-all-hyperlinks-in-outlook-html-and-copy-to-excel